# How to create the same subfolders for file extensions that I'm moving to another directory in Python?

Tags: python, shutil

Here's what I got, some of the files have similar name because of it's gif source but exist in different folders. so I would run into the error of name already exist.

What can I do to have the subfolders recreate in the new folder destination?

```
import os
import shutil
'''
shutil.move() method syntax: shutil.move(source, destination, copy)
source: string representing path of the source 
destination: string representing path of destination 
os.walk() returns a list of main directory's subdirectory's and files
'''
print("Contents of source and destination before moving:")
# path of the source from where data is to be moved
source = r"D:\PS"
# path of the destination where the data is to be copied
destination = r"C:\Users\Username\Desktop\gifs"
# contents of source path
for root, dir, files in os.walk(source):
    print(root)
    print(dir)
    print(files)
# contents of source path before moving
print(os.listdir(destination))
# moving text files
for root, dir, files in os.walk(source):
    for file in files:
        if ".gif" in file:  # checking if the file is a text file by looking for .txt extension in the name of the file
            shutil.move(os.path.join(root, file), destination)
            # os.path.join method is used to join the root path string and file name string
# contents of directories after moving files
print("Contents of destination after moving:")
# contents of destination path after moving text files
print(os.listdir(destination))
```

Answer (score 0):

> What can I do to have the subfolders recreate in the new folder destination?

You need to get the relative path of each file's `root` filepath from the `source` directory. This can be done with [`os.path.relpath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.relpath). Once you have that, you can create the directory and any parent directories that don't yet exist with [`pathlib.Path.mkdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.mkdir).

You can more reliably check if a filename is of a particular extension by using [`str.endswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith), as opposed to using the `in` operator which could return True if `.gif` is found elsewhere in the filename.

```py
import shutil
import pathlib
import os

source = r"D:\PS"
destination = r"C:\Users\Username\Desktop\gifs"

# dir is never used, so it is discarded by assigning it to _
for root, _, filenames in os.walk(source):
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith(".gif"):
            source_filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
            destination_dir = os.path.join(destination, os.path.relpath(root, source))
            pathlib.Path(destination_dir).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
            shutil.move(source_filepath, destination_dir)
            
            # Show the value of each variable
            print(f"{root=!s}")
            print(f"{filename=!s}")
            print(f"{source_filepath=!s}")
            print(f"{destination_dir=!s}")
            print()
```

Output:

```
root=D:\PS\Hans Moleman Productions
filename=Man Getting Hit By Football.gif
source_filepath=D:\PS\Hans Moleman Productions\Man Getting Hit By Football.gif
destination_dir=C:\Users\Username\Desktop\gifs\Hans Moleman Productions
```